# wired based remote mysql server connection with user and password

Tags: java, mysql

I am working with two system in wired internet. One is mysql database server and another is java client application. Both computer are connected to internet via wire. So My problem is , I can not connect to remote server using username and password. But with Netbeans IDE i can able to connect but after making jar file i can't not connect?

my connection code is : "jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.107:3306/db_store", "user", "pass"

What would be the problem ? and how can i solve it? thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, you *can* connect to the server using **the exact same code** when it's running within the Netbeans IDE, just not when it's exported to a .JAR and executed on the same runtime platform? Which error is given?

Comment: @AlexT. When i run from Netbeans it works , And after exporting .Jar it can  connect also , but i can not able to store some data to the server from remote client. And same with POS printer. The POS printer works fine when running from Netbeans but after exporting jars it can not. What is this problem ?